# bash: Is there a way to use tab completion through out CDPATH?

Tags: linux, bash

After reading [this article](http://caliban.org/bash/), I set `CDPATH=.:~`. However, I do not have tab completion through the directories in my home directory. I was wondering if anyone was aware of ways to do this.

Comment: I don't think that setting CDPATH gives you tab completion.  It allows you to cd to a sub-directory of any of the directories listed by just entered the sub-directory name.

Comment: On my Ubuntu desktop system, I can type "cd D" (in a directory other than ~) and press Tab twice and see "Desktop/    Documents/  Downloads/" as proposed destinations. Do you not get similar behavior?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should install and enable [bash-completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion) — it defines a `_cd` function and sets it as the completer for the `cd` command, which overrides the default completion and includes `$CDPATH`.

Comment: It works on mac too. The answer link is broken but it was easy to locate the package in `brew`.